# Показать пароль по кнопке

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, есть следующий код:

```
<div class="group-box">
    <input type="password" id="password-show" class="modal-input" placeholder="Пароль">
    <button type="button" class="show-password"><img src="img/show-password.png" alt="show-pass" /></button>
</div>
```

И следующий JQuery-код:

```
$('button.show-password').click(function() {
    if($('#password-show').attr('type').val() == 'password') {
        $('#password-show').attr('type').val() = 'text';
    } else {
        $('#password-show').attr('type').val() == 'text';
    }
});
```

Почему-то это не работает. Возникает ошибка **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).val is not a function**

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В else два равно, тоесть порверка вместо присвоения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод attr(), если не передавать второй параметр, возвращает значение  атрибута, указанного в первом параметре. Это строковое значение и применение к нему метода val() недопустимо. Если вам надо изменить значение определенного атрибута, то это значение и передается вторым параметром метода attr():

```js
var pass = $('#password-show');
$('button.show-password').click(function() {
  pass.attr('type', pass.attr('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-box">
  <input type="password" id="password-show" class="modal-input" placeholder="Пароль">
  <button type="button" class="show-password">
    <img src="img/show-password.png" alt="show-pass" />
  </button>
</div>
```